# What's the purpose of MergeField '\v' switch in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

The Office documentation for MergeField only [mentions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-MergeField-field-7a6d24a1-68a6-4b05-8359-1dc087daf4e6) the following:

> **\v**
>
> Enables character conversion for vertical formatting.

and the same is copied to a bunch of websites, but without real explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What's the purpose of MergeField '\v' switch?

It appears that the `\v` option is meant for East Asian language
documents where the characters are laid out vertically.

This might help your understanding:

> As far as I know the `\v` switch is intended for East Asian language
>   documents where the characters are laid out vertically.
>
> In that case
>   text in Latin character sets can be displayed in two formats. It can
>   either be written so the characters are in their "normal" orientation
>   , but one character below the next, e.g.
>
> ```
> l
> i
> k
> e
>
> t
> h
> i
> s
> ```
>
> or the entire text can in effect be rotated through 90 degrees, so
>   that (if you like) you would have to turn your head sideways to read
>   the text.
>
> Because different characters are used depending on which way you do
>   it, `\v` is used to "convert" the characters for the first layout, and
>   no `\v` does the second layout.
>
> So using `\v` you would only get the vertical layout you want if you
>   selected Page Setup-Document Grid-Text direction-Vertical and
>
> - (a) you may only get to see that option if you have an East Asian language enabled in Office (or in Vista, in Control Panel-Regional
>     settings) and
> - (b) this sets up the entire page for vertical text.

Source  [Default mail merge -vertical orientation of data](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=115662)